# SKlearn predicting tail instead of head

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a simple prediction using LinearRegression. In my mind, this should predict future values, but I'm clearly getting something wrong. It seems like it's getting data from the tail of the dataframe, instead of the most recent datapoints. I'm using google's stock prices and alpha_vantage's
API to get the stock info

```
ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
df, df_meta = ts.get_daily(symbol='GOOGL', outputsize='full')

df = df[['1. open', '2. high', '3. low', '4. close', '5. volume']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['2. high'] - df['4. close']) / df['4. close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['4. close'] - df['1. open']) / df['1. open'] * 100.0
df = df[['4. close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', '5. volume']]

forecast_col = '4. close'

df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))
print(forecast_out)
# Moving columns negatively
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

# Features
X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)
# Labels
y = np.array(df['label'])
y = np.array(df['label'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
# Fit is synonymous with train
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Score is synonymous with test
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)

print(forecast_set, accuracy, forecast_out)
```

It returns values around the 200's, which clearly isn't predictions for 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the tutorial i was following had the dataframe flipped, so that my recent datapoints, were his oldest datapoints. Easily resolved by flipping my own dataframe using:

```
df = df[::-1]
```